# Will MongoClient connection get destroyed after php execution?

Tags: mongodb

I like to know whether the connection still exists to mongo db after the php file executes its script and exists.

Comment: The connection exists per process in PHP, this means that fpm can hold connections past script execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will be closed. There is an explicit way to [close a connection](http://php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.close.php), but

> You should never have to do this under normal circumstances.

Comment: What's the difference between closed and destroyed (assuming that closing also dismantles the connection)?

Comment: @Sammaye I thought that it is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answers i got a better understanding after looking into this http://php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.close.php